# Visual studio context menu remains after uninstallation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I uninstalled Visual Studio Code version 0.5.0. But in windows explorer context menu (right click anywhere in explorer) it still remains "Open with Code". When I click on that I get an error saying application not found. How can I remove that from the right click? My OS is Windows 10 Pro.

I found and deleted registry keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ticino\Command
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ticino\Command    
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Ticino\Command
```

Now it is gone from context menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found and deleted registry keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Ticino\Command
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ticino\Command    
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Ticino\Command
```

Now it is gone from context menu.